# How can I add a custom domain to an SAN for a certificate for consul domains like active.vault.service.consul?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, hashicorp-vault, dnsmasq

Say one has a service provided by Consul, for which `active.[name-of-service].service.consul` is the link it provides to the active host leader for that service. How would I properly set up TLS to that `.consul` domain name?

For example, suppose I have a HashiCorp Vault service, for which HashiCorp Consul provides service discovery with the [HashiCorp Consul DNS interface](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/dns.html) by `active.vault.service.consul`. If more

I've heard that the "-domain" configuration option can be used to change the TLD from .consul to .somethingelse. Can it be changed to .subdomain.mymaindomain.com and have it still work w/o reaching out to corporate DNS? If so, could one potentially get a real subdomain for a consul/vault service and configure our consul DNS queries to answer under that subdomain. That would allow us to use real, trusted, TLS server certificates for securing communications.

However, without using Consul's CA feature, it seems difficult to actually set up a cert that has `active.vault.service.consul` on an SAN.

Do I need to use a private CA for this?

Consul has a [page on how to set up encryption with TLS](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/encryption.html#rpc-encryption-with-tls), but it seems to be more for authenticating clients than for use with domain names.

Anyway, other than self-signed certificates, how does one get TLS for URIs like `https://active.vault.service.consul:8200/sys/health` to work properly?

Comment: // , And, just to repeat/prevent snark, we CAN create our own self-signed certificates in this case. Also, I'm well aware that there are no publicly trusted CAs on Earth that will issue a trusted TLS server certificate to an unowned, non-resolvable TLD. That is not what I'm asking about. Please read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that not only can you do this, but if set up, allows automation of internal Virtual IP Addresses.

Let's assume your site has the domain **nathanbasanese.rocks**. And let's say your service is Redis.

You'd add `"domain": "consul.nathanbasanese.rocks"` to your Consul configuration file, e.g. `/etc/consul/config.json`.

Then, redirect DNS queries using something like DNSMasq (don't forget to donate!) for anything that uses "consul.nathanbasanese.rocks" as its TLD to go to your Consul server running on localhost.

For example,  you could use the following `127.0.0.1#8600` in DNSMasq as the content of your `/etc/dnsmasq.d/consulstuff`.

```
  ## This forwards DNS requests to the local Consul agent.
  ## Check the following link for more details about why:
  ## https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html#dnsmasq-setup
server=/consul/127.0.0.1#8600
server=/consul.nathanbasanese.rocks/127.0.0.1#8600
```

Then, for each node, get a cert with the node's `node_name` as the cert's `CN=` value (make sure to configure the `node_name`s to be certifiable by whatever standard gets you through your CA. using the FQDN should be fine, e.g. `redis001.nathanbasanese.rocks`), and `active.redis.service.consul.nathanbasanese.rocks` as the top SAN.

If you have 25 Redis behind that Consul responds with their nodename(s) to `active.redis.service.consul.nathanbasanese.rocks`, well, you're going to need 25 certs. Yay, security.

I've tested this, and it works well enough on servers that have the consul agent with the configuration above.

You can test with the `curl -v` command, passing the certificate authority's `.cer` file in to `curl`'s `--cacert` parameter if you run into problems with trusting a test CA or something.

Comment: // , Again, if you want to avoid all this hassle in favor of a, ah, different hassle, I think Consul has its own CA. Because HashiCorp.

Comment: // , Perhaps related to the view expressed here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185146/can-i-use-hashicorp-vault-to-restrict-access-to-credentials-based-on-cidr#comment362910_185146

But Redis is an open source product with a commercial offering, too, and I don't see it getting this treatment. I guess it's a case-by-case thing, and I CBA to take it to meta