# If one HashiCorp Vault Policy allows a capability, and another denies it, how does it decide which Policy to honor?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, secrets-management

HashiCorp Vault is an [**open source**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185146/can-i-use-hashicorp-vault-to-restrict-access-to-credentials-based-on-cidr#comment377137_185146) tool for secrets management.

I'm using it for this purpose, and have come across a minor issue. I seemingly cannot deny access to a specific API path.

I've tested this on 2 different Vault clusters. And it seems like I can't deny access to the "sys/leases/lookup" path.

Do "deny" capabilities trump the parts of policies that give explicit capabilities on a path?

It seems that that's not the case, since the capabilities from the default policy are being favored over those in my "deny-leases" policy.

The default policy allows lease lookup:

```
# Allow looking up lease properties. This requires knowing the lease ID ahead
# of time and does not divulge any sensitive information.
path "sys/leases/lookup" {
    capabilities = ["update"]
}
```

And my creatively named "deny-leases" policy, well, you might say that it doesn't allow lease lookup:

```
~ |  vault policy read deny-leases 
path "sys/leases*" { 
 capabilities = ["deny"] 
 }
```

Let's make 'em fight!

```
~ |  vault token create -policy=deny-leases
Key Value
--- -----
token s.10yrKnAdsBaxTErxXxXvAuLt
token_accessor 2c8beef0kPVLuSjtSsStONgs
token_duration 768h
token_renewable true
token_policies ["default" "deny-leases"]
identity_policies []
policies ["default" "deny-leases"]
~ |  export VAULT_TOKEN=s.10yrKnAdsBaxTErxXxXvAuLt
~ |  curl --silent --header "X-Vault-Token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}" --data '{"lease_id": "auth/userpass/login/heyitsme/deadbeefdeadbeef85cbd6edf586527d824e09560987654321123817e96234e93"}' --request PUT "${VAULT_ADDR}/v1/sys/leases/lookup" | jq 
{ 
 "request_id": "f98e2444-357b-bcof-feef-74b58443feef", 
 "lease_id": "", 
 "renewable": false, 
 "lease_duration": 0, 
 "data": { 
 "expire_time": "2019-01-21T17:03:41.72395079-05:00", 
 "id": "auth/userpass/login/heyitsme/deadbeefdeadbeef85cbd6edf586527d824e09560987654321123817e96234e93", 
 "issue_time": "2018-12-20T17:03:41.72395019-05:00", 
 "last_renewal": null, 
 "renewable": true, 
 "ttl": 1049229 
 }, 
 "wrap_info": null, 
 "warnings": null, 
 "auth": null 
} 
~ |
```

Looks like the default policy "wins", here, because its explicit allowing of that capability overrode the explicit denial in the `deny-leases` policy.

How does Vault decide which policy "wins", and how would I restrict access to the lease lookup?

Comment: // , Details are anonymized to protect the guilty.

Comment: This question seems very specific to how Hashicorp Vault was implemented. Would it be more productive to go diving in Vault documentation, and open a service ticket with Hashicorp if it's not described?

Comment: // , Jeff sent me the answer. If one policy has a *, and another doesn't, the one without the * will be honored as being more "specific", as in the yellow warning box here: https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies.html#policy-syntax I had somehow expected that a `deny` capability would override this, given Vault's design principle of default deny.  I'll add my own answer once the heat's died down.

Comment: // , And I'd say it's also a matter of design, rather than just implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short, and unsatisfying partial answer, here, is to just modify the `default` policy to remove or "comment-out" (I know) the `sys/leases/lookup` stanza.

```
#path "sys/leases/lookup" {
#    capabilities = ["update"]
#}
```

Still doesn't answer the broader question of the nitty gritty details of how one set of Policies' `deny` capabilities might or might not override capabilities allowed in another Policy, and where.

Comment: // , Update: `deny` will only override other capabilities if the `deny` capability is on an equally specific path or a MORE specific path than the other capabilities.